# Como fazer para o conteúdo se repita em uma outra página?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando PHP e bootstrap. O corpo é composto de três colunas, as duas laterais elas devem se repetir em todas as outras páginas, queria saber como inseri-las nas outras páginas de uma forma que quando eu altere uma coluna todas as demais páginas recebam também essa alteração?

Comment: Vc pode criar um arquivo coluna.php e dar um include onde vc quiser que ela apareça.

Comment: Também acho que um include resolveria seu problema, aqui tem uma vídeo aula: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZMWuPbKgQA Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer algo parecido com esse menu, porém no seu caso, teria dois menus e no centro o conteúdo.
Assim, você mudando o conteúdo dos menus, que no seu caso seriam as duas colunas laterais, a parte central não mudaria e também você não iria alterar as outras páginas, pois você só teria uma página html.
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/nav-tabs-dropdown

Comment: ainda não compreendi direito